# Rails Active Admin display belongs_to column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How do I display a column from the relational belongs_to record? group.title is the column I want to display. Questions belongs to group.

column :group doesn't display anything

```
index do
selectable_column
id_column
column :question
column :group
actions
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
column :group do |your_model|
  link_to your_model.group.title, admin_group_path(your_model.group)
end
```